# OData ASP.NET Core Web API Get method - pass multiple parameters

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API OData 4 function in which I pass two parameters and configured the route as shown follows.

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("AApp({id},{name})")]
public IActionResult Get([FromODataUri]int id, [FromODataUri]string name)
{
     return Ok(context.AApp.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.AppId == id && 
          x.App == name));
}
```

I have created builder function and passed two parameters in it as shown follows:-

```
var AAppByIdName = builder.Function("AApp");
AAppByIdName.Parameter<int>("id");
AAppByIdName.Parameter<string>("name");
AAppByIdName.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<AApp>("AApp");
```

Now when I run the project, I get the error:

> The path template `AApp({id},{name})` on the action `Get` in controller `MyAppController` is not a valid OData path template. The number of keys specified in the URI does not match number of key properties for the resource `MyNamespace.AspNetCore.Models.AApp`.

Please suggest the fix as I have already created the function parameters and configured the route.

Comment: were you able to find a way how to pass more than one input parameter?